# Can't write to the file second time after the program is closed and run again. Only save for the first time

Tags: java, java-io

I was working on my assignment and found that the textfile which I suppose to write data to,

Data cannot be written twice to it once I close the program and run again. Here is the code

```
public static void writeFile() {

        try {

            PrintWriter writeFile = new PrintWriter(file);

            writeFile.print(buttonC1.getText()+"\t"+ 
                   stdname.getText()+"\t"+mtcnum.getText()+"\t"+cid.getText()+
                 "\t"+spvname.getText()+"\r\n123");

            writeFile.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by can't be written twice? your code is working perfectly at my end. I ma using `new File("file.txt")` to create file.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to run the program again and have it_append_ data to the existing file?

Comment: Yaaa append data to the existing file >< can't think of this term

Comment: `PrintWriter writeFile = new PrintFile(new FileOutputStream(file, true));`  ought to do it.  [`FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-)

Comment: @NgJingXuan You need to make this more clear in the question itself.[Edit] the question and include the info from your comment in the question.We require the info to identify the issue to be part of the question text.Also for future debugging/questions:Try to reduce the issue to a minimum.If you can take one of the parts involved out of the equation,it would be preferable to do so.In this case it would be possible to reproduce the issue without any gui involved.Removing that part also removes the one thing that could be necessary but I've seldomly see question do:include the controls' text

Answer (score 0):

How is "file" created? Is a stacktrace printed? In the catch block, print e.getMessage().

Try this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.txt");

try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer)){

    printWriter.write("Happy days are here again!");
}
```

After the above works, add in your content one step at a time. It is possible one of those elements is causing an issue, like a NullPointerException.

Comment: If you want an upvote or a selected correct answer, you should actually answer the question.  From the clarifications in the comments, it is clear that the question is really -> "How do I append to a file?"  For which Kevin supplied an answer in a comment.  Copy Kevin's comment to your answer and explain it well and I'm sure you will get upvotes and reputation.